# excel indicate range of numbers by smallest and largest defined in two individual cells

Tags: excel

I'm looking to find missing numbers within 1000s of numbers in the first column.

I came across this formula;

```
=SMALL(IF(ISNA(MATCH(ROW(A$1:A$30),A$1:A$30,0)),ROW(A$1:A$30)),ROW(A1))
```

which works, except there is a problem.

In the formula it is using row numbers 1 to 30 , as defined by A$1:A$30  for lookup value in the MATCH formula

MATCH(lookup_value, lookup_array, [match_type])

in my application, the number of rows is not always going to be the same.  I need to be able to indicate the range of values of which I want it to be compared against. By defining the min and max

I intent to feed it well into thousands of set of numbers each with thousands of rows. So changing the lookup value by row range everytime is not going to be feasible.

I want it to be able to read this range with min and max defined in two other cells.

As such;

```
=SMALL(IF(ISNA(MATCH(*1 to 5000*,A$1:A$30,0)),ROW(A$1:A$30)),ROW(A1))
```

where 1 is in cell lets say E1 and 5000 is in cell E2
**obviously this doesn't work, so i'm looking for an answer regarding on how to define a range of numbers with min and max in two other cells.**

Comment: would help if you could post a snippet of what the data looks like

Answer (score 0):

Use INDEX to return the correct range:

```
=SMALL(IF(ISNA(MATCH(ROW(INDEX(A:A,$E$1):INDEX(A:A,$E$2)),A:A,0)),ROW(INDEX(A:A,$E$1):INDEX(A:A,$E$2))),ROW(A1))
```

This is an array formula and must be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

[image]